# Can you create a DAO on cardano using only native tokens or would it require a sidechain?

Tags: decentralized-applications

I am researching creating a community-driven dapp with tokenomics similar to steem. Can someone point me in the right direction regarding implementation on the cardano ecosystem? I can not find a lot of information regarding DAO's and sidechains on cardano.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be asking for a technical answer to a non-technical question. As far as I understand it, a DAO is simply a way of conceptualizing a distributed/decentralized system for decision making. The specifics by which such a system is implemented can vary greatly depending on the needs of the organization/application. It can be as simple a trusted relationship between *n* parties with all transactions on mainchain, to as complex as a hydra head with its own monetary policy facilitating arbitrary business logic.

Really just depends what the DAO is intended for.